# Swig : How to get string in a callback

Tags: c#, c++, swig

I achieved interoperability between C# & C++ using SWIG.
However, the C ++ to C # callback does not work properly.
If you pass "std::wstring" to the callback on the C++ side, it will be treated as a "string" on the C# side, but only the first character of the string passed on the C++ side will be stored.

My goal is using "std::string" in argument of callback.

Creating a base class with virtual function in C++ and derive a class in C# which implement the virtual method.
I referred to this link.
[Callback from C++ to C# using SWIG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59657232/callback-from-c-to-c-sharp-using-swig)

My code what callback from C++ to C# using SWIG is following.

**C++ : Header.h**

```c++
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class CallbackBase
{
public:
    virtual void Callback(const  std::wstring& str) = 0;
};

class CppClass
{
public:
    void SetString(const std::wstring &str);    
    std::wstring GetString();
    void SetCallback(CallbackBase& callbackObject);
    void ExeCallback();

private:
    std::wstring string;
    CallbackBase* pCallbackObj = NULL;
    void InvokeCallback();
};

typedef CppClass* (*GetInstanceFuncPointer)(void);

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) CppClass * CreateInstance(void);
```

**C++ : Impl.cpp**

```c++
#include <thread>
#include "Header.h"

void CppClass::SetString(const  std::wstring& str)
{
    string = str;
}

std::wstring CppClass::GetString()
{
    return string;
}

void CppClass::SetCallback(CallbackBase &callbackObj)
{
    pCallbackObj = &callbackObj;
}

void CppClass::ExeCallback()
{
    std::thread *th = new std::thread(&CppClass::InvokeCallback, this);
    th->join();
}

void CppClass::InvokeCallback()
{
    if (pCallbackObj != NULL)
    {
        pCallbackObj->Callback(string);
    }
}

__declspec(dllexport) CppClass* CreateInstance(void)
{
    return new CppClass;
}
```

**Swig : Interface file**

```c++
%include <windows.i> 
%include <wchar.i>
%include <std_wstring.i>

%module (directors="1") MyDLL
 
%{
#include "Header.h"
%}
%feature("director") CallbackBase;
%include "Header.h"
```

**C# : main.cs**

```c#
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace CsharpApp
{
    public class MyCallback : CallbackBase
    {
        public override void Callback(string str)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"str = {str}"); // --> str = H
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyCallback myCallbackObj = new MyCallback();
            CppClass instance = MyDLL.CreateInstance();
            string str = "Hello World!";
            instance.SetString(str);
            Debug.WriteLine($"str = {instance.GetString()}"); // --> str = Hello World!
            instance.SetCallback(myCallbackObj);
            instance.ExeCallback();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the string twice on the C# side.
The first is "GetString()" in the main function.
In this case, "Hello World!" Is stored.
The second time I get it as an argument of the callback function.
In this case, only "H" is stored.

How can I correctly store the string in the callback function argument?

Comment: I changed the argument of the callback function from std::wstring to std::string and it didn't cause any problems.  

Apparently, it seems to be a phenomenon only when std::wstring.  

I couldn't solve it, but I'm going to use std :: string.

Comment: I have done this numerous times between `C++` and `Python` - not really fond of `C#`. Your `std::thread` leaks. Could you try simply executing the callback in the main thread. Also, the overload of `const std::string&` is that matching `string` in `C#`. Try no threads and an integer argument, next a pointer to a static string (living in C++), finally something heap allocated

Comment: Something somewhere has picked out the wrong typemaps for wstring and tried to do it as `char *` instead, which since 'H' is an ascii character is null at byte 2. If I had to bet on a culprit I'd go looking at wchar.i first in the director argument typemaps, but I'm not at all sure....

Comment: @JensMunk  
> Your std::thread leaks.  
I'm sorry, I overlooked it.
Please ignore it as it is not the essence of this issue.

Comment: @Flexo

> which since 'H' is an ascii character is null at byte 2. 
It does!
Certainly the second byte is NULL.