# How to call a C# method from C using SWIG?

Tags: c#, c, swig

I have been searching for some explanations/code snippets that illustrate how to call a C# method from C using SWIG. The best that I could find is this: [Callback from C++ to C# using SWIG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59657232/callback-from-c-to-c-sharp-using-swig). Alas, this is for C++ and not C. How can we achieve the same functionality but for C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using SWIG to help (a little) still, but fundamentally if you're using a C compiler you can't enable SWIG directors, which the example you linked to relies upon:

```
test.i:1: Error: Directors are not supported for C code and require the -c++ option
```

So you'll have to rebuild some parts of that functionality in C in order to do this. I built an example of a C++ enabled director/callbacks setup and used that as a basis to build my understanding of the C# mechanics. Let's work this through backwards, starting with the test we want to run:

```
public class TestImpl : CallbackInterface {
    public override void callback() {
        System.Console.WriteLine("handling event...");
    }

    public static void Main() {
        CallbackInterface cb = new TestImpl();
        test.test_runner(cb);   
    }
}
```

We want to define an abstract class, `CallbackInterface` that we can pass instances around and have our C code call the C# `callback` implementation.

Here's my .i SWIG interface file:

```
%module test
%{
#include <assert.h>
%}

%typemap(csclassmodifiers) struct CallbackInterface "public abstract class";
%typemap(cscode) struct CallbackInterface %{
  public delegate void callback0(); // [2]

  public CallbackInterface() : this(null) { // [3]
    connect();
  }

  private void connect() {
    setCallback(new callback0(callback));
  }

  public abstract void callback();
%}

// [4]
%typemap(cstype) cb0 "CallbackInterface.callback0";
%typemap(imtype) cb0 "CallbackInterface.callback0";
%typemap(csin) cb0 "$csinput";
%ignore CallbackInterface::cb;

%extend struct CallbackInterface {
  CallbackInterface(cb0 cb) { // [3]
    struct CallbackInterface *ret = malloc(sizeof *ret);
    ret->cb = cb;
    return ret;
  }

  void setCallback(cb0 cb) {
    $self->cb = cb;
  }
}

%inline %{
  typedef void (*cb0)();

  struct CallbackInterface {
    cb0 cb; // [1]
  };

  static void test_runner(struct CallbackInterface *interface) {
    assert(interface->cb);
    fprintf(stderr, "Doing test, pointer=%p, cb=%p\n", interface, interface->cb);
    interface->cb();
  }
%}
```

From investigating the normal directors implementation in C# it seems that the C++ layer is working with function pointers through the pinvoke interface. So we define a struct in our interface at 1, which has a single member, a function pointer.

In order to actually get a function pointer out of our C# code we need to use a delegate, we've set things up for this at 2, which is C# code that's going to be part of our `CallbackInterface` class.

In SWIG we've "extended" (but just using C still) our struct to provide a constructor, which takes a delegate as an argument at 3. This is a little bit weird, because we only pass `null` in here, but that works as a handy overload for our default constructor later and ensures that we do at least initalise the `cb` member of the struct too when we create an instance, with a delegated constructor call at 3. (Aside: I originally tried to create the delegate here, but this is a static context it would seem so you can't do that at this point). Then inside the body of the default constructor we call our private `connect` method that sets up a delegate and uses our `%extend` `setCallback` method to actually modify the struct.

If you were so inclined you could provide an overload of `setCallback` as well, such that C function pointers can be set up as handlers, but that's an added extra especially given the C limitation means you can't write classes at all. With some extra typemaps at 4 to make sure that the delegate gets passed through to the C as a function pointer we're in business and so this Makefile below can run and test things for us:

```
.PHONY: run

all: run

test_wrap.c: test.i
    swig -csharp -Wall -debug-tmsearch test.i

test.cs: test_wrap.c
CallbackInterface.cs: test_wrap.c
testPINVOKE.cs: test_wrap.c

test.exe: test.cs runme.cs CallbackInterface.cs testPINVOKE.cs
    mcs $^

libtest.so: test_wrap.c
    gcc -shared -Wall -Wextra $^ -o $@ -fPIC

run: test.exe libtest.so
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./test.exe
```

With Mono on Ubuntu at least that does work as expected.